# array_multisort() - What does it mean that relative order of equal members is undefined

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, array-multisort

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

This is like the "fifth" line there:

> *Note: If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the
>   sorted array is undefined.*

Can you give me an example / explanation of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Means that if `a == b` then in your sorted array you can have either `a,b` or `b,a`.

Comment: It means that if you compare f.e. `(a, b)` with `(a, c)` by their first component (`a`) they are equal but their can land in any order in the sorted array.

Comment: I think that the explanation could be better, especially as far as the "relative" part. Would somebody be able to come up with a code example that shows what this means. Also, I am learning the PHP and I know that it would be good to know the underlying C language to check what this means (it is possible to check the source code and see what it would do and why). Either way, an explanation could be better, I think. Possibly this? -> https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L5598

Comment: You simply need to get used to the word "undefined" as used in computing. It simply means exactly what it says: it has not been defined what the order *should* be, so it will be *some* order. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ E.g. an alternative would be that it has been defined that the original order of the elements will be kept. But that is not the case. It's simply *not clearly defined* what the order of two equal elements should be.

Answer (score 1):

It means that if two items are considered equal, it is unpredictable which one will come first and their relative order is random for all intents and purposes.

Comment: I think that it needs to be added as a comment, not an answer as others did. Up-to-you

Comment: @AlivetoDie It's an answer to the question, so why post it as a comment?

Comment: Multiple time issue raised by others when someone with less reputation trying to add the same kind of answer. As well as others already answer before this in comments. You can check that. I have no issue with this answer  BTW